# Python: Plotting time series data in Zeppelin causes ValueError alternate times

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to plot a time series data in Zeppelin, but I get ValueError for every alternate run of my plot function.

Here's a sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=10, freq='M')
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)

# Plotting the data:

orig = plt.plot(ts)
plt.show()
```

Running this code for the first time results in `ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1`, but the plot appears when I run the code again (in the same cell). But the error again returns in the third run, and so on. Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_python-2526037595738258825.py", line 282, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_python-2526037595738258825.py", line 275, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/flytxt_libs/forecasting/time_series.py", line 37, in stationarity_test
    orig = plt.plot(timeseries, color='blue', label='Original')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3318, in plot
    ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1892, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1406, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 407, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 385, in _plot_args
    x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 217, in _xy_from_xy
    bx = self.axes.xaxis.update_units(x)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1424, in update_units
    self._update_axisinfo()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1442, in _update_axisinfo
    self.set_major_locator(info.majloc)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1543, in set_major_locator
    self.stale = True
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 279, in stale
    self.stale_callback(self, val)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 76, in _stale_axes_callback
    self.axes.stale = val
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 279, in stale
    self.stale_callback(self, val)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 56, in _stale_figure_callback
    self.figure.stale = val
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 279, in stale
    self.stale_callback(self, val)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 576, in _auto_draw_if_interactive
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
  File "/usr/local/zeppelin/interpreter/lib/python/backend_zinline.py", line 136, in draw_idle
    self.draw(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 464, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 63, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1143, in draw
    renderer, self, dsu, self.suppressComposite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 139, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 63, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2409, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, dsu)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 139, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 63, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1136, in draw
    ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 969, in _update_ticks
    tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 912, in iter_ticks
    majorLocs = self.major.locator()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 983, in __call__
    self.refresh()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 1003, in refresh
    dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 760, in viewlim_to_dt
    return num2date(vmin, self.tz), num2date(vmax, self.tz)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 401, in num2date
    return _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 254, in _from_ordinalf
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1
```

Interestingly, the same code works fine in Jupyter notebook 5.3.1 without any such issues.

My Zeppelin version is 0.7.2 and matplotlib version is 2.0.0.

Could someone please tell me why this happen?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have updated the post with simpler code. Please have a look. Thanks!

Comment: I have never worked with Zeppelin, so I cannot help here; I just wanted to help you write a question that allows people to help you. Which you have done - you might also add what exactly you mean by "the next try", is it running the same code cell again, or copying the code to a new cell?

Comment: @ImportanceofBeingErnest I mean when I tried to run the same code again, in the same cell. Thanks for pointing out the confusion. Will update the question again.